# Why small black bars at top and bottom sides in (6,6s,6plus simulators)when i load Launcher screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

Hi i am very new for ios and in my app i am loading Launcher screens they are(Default-568h@2x,Default,Default@2x) ok that's fine

When i run my app 4,5,5s simulators screen is fitting perfectly see my 5s simulator screen

But when i load my app in 6,6s,6plus simulators small little bit gap coming at top and bottom side see my below 6 simulator screen

what is the problem is it sumulator problem or any other problem please guide me

### 5 simulator screen:-

[image]

### 6 simulator screen:-

[image]

Comment: see my 6 simulator there top and bottom small i mean little bit gap came with block color ,did you observe?

Comment: Have you tried launching on a real device? I assume you don't have one to test on.

Comment: no we have only 5,4s devices and 6,6plus devices we don't have that's why i run in simulator

Comment: Are you adding these images through the pre-configured LaunchImage in your Assets.xcassets file?

Comment: i just drag this launcher screen images to my project file one folder

Comment: where is your 3x  images

Comment: i set only this images Default-568h@2x,Default,Default@2x

Answer (score 0):

This is because your app is not optimised for larger iPhone screens. You will notice that is not just the black lines at the top and bottom that you are getting but also an overly magnified status bar and content.

A good article on how to fix this is here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/89816/porting-app-iphone-6-iphone-6-plus-ios-8-top-10-tips