# Small black bars at top and bottom sides in (6,6s,6plus simulators)when i load Launcher screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

Hi i am very new for ios and in my app i am loading Launcher screens they are(Default-568h@2x.png,Default.png,Default@2x.png,Default-414w-736h@3x~iphone.jpeg,Default-375w-667h@2x~iphone.jpeg) ok that's fine

When i run my app 4,5,5s simulators screen is fitting perfectly see my 5s simulator screen

But when i load my app in 6,6s,6plus simulators small little bit gap coming at top and bottom side see my below 6 simulator screen

what is the problem is it sumulator problem or any other problem please guide me

### 5 inch simulator:-

[image]

### 6 inch simulator:-

[image]

Comment: Hi why this problem is coming i am suffering fro this @EI Captain

Comment: Try viewing simulator in full view mode by pressing Command + 1

Comment: yes same small block bars are coming after done this, is it simulator problem

Comment: i dont have 6 inch device for checking this in real device

Comment: Probably is should be a simulator problem, as Xcode simulators could not simulate the Retina and actual device correctly.

Comment: ok ok thanks for ur suggestions,And actually i don't have 6 inch real device other i would have checked this in real device

Comment: @AbhiRam -- your question is good one I tried in multiple ways , but I am not get the answer .

Comment: bro this is simulator issue i think, Xcode simulators could not simulate the Retina and actual device correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why small black bars at top and bottom sides in (6,6s,6plus simulators)when i load Launcher screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35812178/why-small-black-bars-at-top-and-bottom-sides-in-6-6s-6plus-simulatorswhen-i-lo)

Comment: Please use .png format images for default and make sure that size and formate befor added image and use that image in image.assest.

Answer (score 0):

This is just simulator issue in real device, bars will not appear.

Comment: are u sure @Roshan Soni?

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any problem and warnings if your images have these resolutions:

> Retina HD 4.7

Default-iPhone6.png (750 x 1334) – "iPhone Portrait iOS8 – Retina HD 4.7"

> Retina HD 5.5

Default-iPhone6Plus.png (1242 x 2208) – "iPhone Portrait iOS8 – Retina HD 5.5" and "iPhone Landscape iOS8 – Retina HD 5.5"

Comment: so if i add this launcher screen images that block bar not appear right?

Comment: are that images must be in .png formate or they should be .jpeg not problem?

Comment: Hi @Mirsat Murutoglu u there?

Comment: They cannot be jpeg, xcode does not allow that. If you do that it will crash.

Comment: so as u saying that it must be png formate,Ok i will try and just meet u

Comment: no no again same problem is coming if if dont' mind can i send my sample x code file just see once please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105535/discussion-between-abhiram-and-mirsat-murutoglu).